# Count giving wrong amount in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to get the amount of items I have based on what I have in my rank column. So if I have 3 items that has a rank of high then I want it to show 3 and if I have a rank of low and it has 2 items I need it to show 2.

But the issue I'm having is that it's counting all my items so I'm getting a count of 5.

Here is my code

```
    $items = Item::all();
    
    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        if($item->rank === 'high')
        {
            $count = $item->count();
            dd($count);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter collection:

```
$items = Item::all();

$highRank = $items->filter(function ($value, $key) {
     return $value->rank == 'high';
});

$highRank->count();
```

More detail with this collection check this doc: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-filter

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by `rank` and get the `count`

```
$Items = Item::select('rank', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                 ->groupBy('rank')
                 ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

simple used

```
$items = Item::where('rank','high')->get()->count();
```